# I'm looking for a shorter/better way to get the first object from and NSSet in my Core Data app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsset

Currently I have this code :

```
if let myPhoneNumbers = person.phoneNumbers?.allObjects as? [PhoneNumber] {
        for myPhoneNumber in myPhoneNumbers {
        mainPhoneNumber = myPhoneNumber.number
        break
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way of coding this. I know that `NSSet` is unordered and probably is the reason it does not have its own implementation of `.first` such as:

```
person.phoneNumbers.first
```

But I'm thinking my code is not the most elegant code and maybe not proper Swift code.

Comment: sort your NSSet and take the first object

Comment: myPhoneNumbers is an array, so you can do `myPhoneNumbers.first` instead of using a for loop.

Comment: Why would you want the first object of a set? You said it yourself, `NSSet` is unordered, you'll get arbitrary phone numbers every time, with no consistency

Comment: Why are you setting the `mainPhoneNumber` to another number each time you go through the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `myPhoneNumbers` is an array, so you could use `myPhoneNumbers.first` instead of looping.

```
if let myPhoneNumbers = person.phoneNumbers?.allObjects as? [PhoneNumber] {
    mainPhoneNumber = myPhoneNumbers.first
}
```

However, as has been pointed out, you should impose some sort of order on your set, so that the result of executing this code is the same for any given set. Arbitrary results are usually bad.

Since you mentioned you are using Core Data, I suggest adding a convenience property on your Person entity to return the phone numbers as a sorted array.

If your entities look something like this...

```
class PhoneNumber: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var number: String
}

class PersonEntity: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var phoneNumbers: NSSet?
}
```

...you could create a convenience property like this:

```
class PersonEntity: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var phoneNumbers: NSSet?

    // Arrays are often easier to work with than sets, 
    //  so provide a convenience property that returns
    //  phone numbers sorted
    var phoneNumbersArray: [PhoneNumber] {
        get {
            if let phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers {
                return (phoneNumbers.allObjects as! [PhoneNumber]).sorted() {
                    // here, sorting by phone number, but
                    // you can sort on whatever you want
                    $1.number > $0.number
                }
            }
            // return empty array if set is nil
            return [PhoneNumber]()
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, get the first number with one line of code like this:

```
mainPhoneNumber = person.phoneNumbersArray.first
```

I like to add this type of convenience array property to all my entities that have sets. Arrays are easier to work with, in my opinion. Here I chose to return an empty array instead of a nil array, when the set is nil. This works if you are OK with treating nil and empty phone sets the same.

Also note that `.first` returns nil if `phoneNumbersArray` is empty.

Comment: Awesome comment. I may not use your explanation or code in this entity but I do have another entity that will get this upgrade. Woohou!! Thanks

Comment: Be mindful that this is highly inneficient if you're dealing with many records as you are fetching all objects in a relationship when you just need one.

Comment: It's better to just store the phone numbers as an array, in the first place. This is all so unnecessarily over-complicated.

Comment: @Alexander In Core Data, a one-to-many relationship is represented using NSSet.

Comment: @MikeTaverne Oh right, fair point. In that case, I still defer to the suggestion in my answer: `I think it's much better for the user to determine what constitutes the main number. Perhaps store a reference to the "main" PhoneNumber object inside the Person.`

Comment: @PatrickMiron Core Data has the concept of a fetched property which is "represented by an array (NSArray), not a set (NSSet). The fetch request associated with the property can have a sort ordering, and thus the fetched property may be ordered." See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW13

Comment: Thanks Mike, so the person.phoneNumbers?.allObjects I get back should be a NSArray and not an NSSet?  By the way guys, I used person.phoneNumbers because it was data types similar to another situation I have.

Comment: Ok... I may be reading the comments in the wrong order. Is it an NSArray or and NSSet? /#*&@^ I'm going coocoo!

Comment: My last comment on fetched properties had nothing to do with my original answer. You can ignore that comment. Sorry for the confusion. My original answer stands.

Comment: allObjects returns an array [Any]

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea why you would ever want to get the arbitrary "first" element of a set, but here you go:

```
let first = (person.phoneNumbers?.allObjects as? [PhoneNumber])?.first
```

This will give more/less random results. Here are my recommendations:

- Store the phone numbers in an array, so that a user's ordering of phone numbers is preserved.
- I think it's much better for the user to determine what constitutes the main number. Perhaps store a reference to the "main" `PhoneNumber` object inside the `Person`.

Comment: You are right, getting the first object or any object in an NSSet is pretty much the same thing as the order is not guaranteed, so might as well call `set.anyObject()` instead.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `anyObject`. What use case could there possibly for something like that?

Comment: The reason I want the first number to come up is that I want to be able to assign more then one phone number per person and in this view controller I did not need a specific number, just one to show up and if the user clicks on the cell he would get more details on it. I wanted the first number entered by the user to be a convenient way to show up first. Further thinking about it I will probably replace this by something else. I wanted some order to the inputed phone numbers, just in case for example a person has more then one phone number that has a type = "mobile" Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickMiron But as YOU said yourself, sets aren't ordered. The order the user entered in the phone numbers in has absolutely no effect in determining the order they appear in the set.

Comment: I was trying to see if I could return the first object. It makes no sense in this context, your right. But this raises another question of mine would it not return the first object it inserted in the NSSet in the first place or that also means it might or might not. ... But if I understand Mike Tavern's comment above, Core Data is returning me an NSArray which I believe is a subclass of NSSet, or are the fetchedObjects actually an NSSet... I'm gonna go coocoo!

Comment: By the way thanks Alexander. I appreciate your input!

Comment: @PatrickMiron I don't think you understand. NSSet. Does. Not. Preserve. Order. If you put `1, 2, 3` into a set in that order, and then get `allObjects`, the resulting array could be `[3, 2, 1]`, or `[2, 3, 1]`, `[2, 1, 3]`, or maybe (by complete consequence) `[1, 2, 3]`. Sets. Don't. Preserve. Order. Getting the first makes no sense, that's why set doesn't have a `.first` property.

Comment: Actually, your absolutely right. Even for my real data, I realized I was using the wrong idea behind and didn't even need to return its first object. I only needed to stop at the first object it found and even that became irrelevant when I check if the NNSet was not empty. Thanks guy! I appreciate your answer and now that I look at my question, I must have had low blood sugar since I was mixing things up. Cheers!